# Maximum number of domains that can be assigned to one Heroku app?

Tags: heroku, dns

I am discussing a project with a client who wants his users to access the app via their own domain name if they so choose…

**Is there a limit on the number of custom domains that can be assigned to one Heroku application?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no limit to the number of domains you can add on an app, from the [docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#heroku-setup):

```
You can add any number of domains to a single app
```

Comment: I just got in touch with support and as of Nov 2013 they still have no limit on the number of custom domains that you can add.

Comment: I've updated [the article](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#domain-types) to be a bit more clear here: "A single application can have any number of domains assigned to it...". Sorry for the ambiguity.

Answer (score 7):

The [Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#rules-on-adding-domains) now state a limit of 1,000 custom domains per app.

Answer (score 1):

The limit is now 10,000 custom domains per-app, according to [Heroku's docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#rules-on-adding-domains).