# How many custom domain can I have on Heroku for same app

Tags: heroku

I'm building an application where I'll have many (like several thousands) domains pointing to. Is there a limit how many custom domains the application may have in heroku ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, as per the official [documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#rules-on-adding-domains):

> A single app can have up to 10,000 custom domains assigned to it

There was a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15773920/maximum-number-of-domains-that-can-be-assigned-to-one-heroku-app), but the limit has been introduced after the answer was accepted